# SQL Server Case Count In Subquery Jelp?

Tags: sql-server-2008, aggregate-functions, case

There are many kinds of statusid in my table. Certain values mean that work in the table is "complete".

If something is "complete", all of the statusid values for a grouped checkid are
1 or 10 or 40. Statusid values are not consecutive (there are many statusid values, this is just an extract). Can someone show how I can do an In Clause in a case subquery, or just a cleaner way to write this?

Expected result set

```
    checkid    iscomplete
    3           0
    4           1
    5           0
    6           0
```

4 is complete because there is only one row and it has a "10".
3 is not complete because one of the values is "1" but the others are "2".
5 is not complete because it only has "30" values.
6 is not complete because it has one "40" but it also has one "30".

DML:

```
create table #test1 ( test1id int identity primary key , checkid int  , statusid int )
insert into #test1 ( checkid , statusid ) values (3 , 1)
insert into #test1 ( checkid , statusid ) values (3 , 2)
insert into #test1 ( checkid , statusid ) values (3 , 2)
insert into #test1 ( checkid , statusid ) values (4 , 10)
insert into #test1 ( checkid , statusid ) values (5 , 30)
insert into #test1 ( checkid , statusid ) values (5 , 30)
insert into #test1 ( checkid , statusid ) values (6 , 30)
insert into #test1 ( checkid , statusid ) values (6 , 40)

select  checkid 
, iscomplete =  ( case when count(*) Where #test1.statusid In ( 1,10,40) Then 1 )
from #test1
group by checkid
```

Error:

> An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a
>   condition is expected, near 'Where'.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to write a query to meet the requirement is:

```
SELECT
    t.checkid,
    CASE 
        WHEN COUNT_BIG(*) = COUNT
            (
            CASE 
                WHEN t.statusid IN (1,10,40)
                THEN 1 
                ELSE NULL 
            END
            ) 
        THEN 1 
        ELSE 0 
    END
FROM #test1 AS t
GROUP BY
    t.checkid
ORDER BY
    t.checkid;
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the `COUNT`(expression) aggregate does not count `NULL` (aisde: though `COUNT(*)` will).  For a group where all the entries are status 1, 10 or 40, the nested `CASE` will return 1 for every row in that group, equalling COUNT(*) for the group.  If even one member of the group is not status 1, 10, or 40, the nested `CASE` will return `NULL`, which will not be counted by `COUNT`.